Is there a way to find multiple values in excel?
what I want to do, is to look for multiple values using a date, and Id. For example, I want to get both codes from the same person, and the same date. For reference, please see picture

I tried using vlookup, index (match(), match()), but so far I have not succeeded. Is this posible?

FILTER() function or INDEX()+AGGREGATE()
